# Find the value of $1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2.........-199^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Find the value of

$1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2.........-199^2$

What I did:-
I separated the positive terms and negative terms

$(1^2+5^2+9^2....195^2)$-$(3^2+7^2+......199^2)$

$(1^2-0)+(5^2-3^2)+......(195^2-191^2)-199^2$

But this method doesn't give me the correct answer

What is wrong in my way of doing it? Where is the mistake?

Comment: $(2n+1)^2-(2n-1)^2=8n$

Comment: How to calculate n?

Comment: what to calculate $n$? Put $n=1$, you get $3^2-1^2=8$, put $n=3$, you get $7^2-5^2=8\times 3=24$, like this.... now sum up. In your case you need to calculate $199=2n+1$, when you get $n$, you just sum over odd numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed $197^2$, and perhaps a different pairing might be helpful. I'll denote your sum with $S$.

\begin{align*}
-S &= (3^2-1^2) + (7^2-5^2) + \dotsb +  (199^2-197^2)\\
&= 2(1+3+\dotsb + 199)\\
&= 20000\\
S &= -20000
\end{align*}

where line 2 to line 3 is from arithmetric progression $\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}=\frac{100(1+199)}{2}$. The value $n=100$ could be found from $2n-1=199$.

Comment: Why -S? @JirapatSamranvedhya

Comment: and answer is 19800

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to multiply by 2. I used $-S$ because I don't want to write minus sign too many times.

Comment: But 9-1=8. Gives a positive value. Why - then? @JirapatSamranvedhya

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. I intentionally used $-S$ to get positive value on the right hand side.

Comment: got it. sorry....

Comment: It's correct. This command in a terminal checks the result: `python -c "print(sum((-1)**k*(2*k+1)**2 for k in range(100)))"`. You could perhaps explain how you get from line 2 to line 3.

Comment: Added. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} [(4i-3)^2-(4i-1)^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{8-16i} = 8n- 8n(n+1)=-8n^2.$$
Calculate $n$ by using $4n-1=199$.

Comment: How to calculate n? @MathLover